# Calculate accumulated distance with road network

Tags: raster, arcmap, distance, network-analyst, accumulated

I am working on a project in ArcMap and the task I am working on goes as follows:

- Calculate the accumulated distance (in meters) of every pixel on the
  map to Itaituba taking the road network into account (yellow vector lines).
- The final output should cover only the state of Mato Grosso but as
  the port of Itaituba is located in Pará, it will be necessary to use
  other states area and road network for the modeling.
- Use the Itaituba port as reference for destination
- Resolution of the final output 100m

I have worked with the Network Analyst of ArcMap before but never done accumulated distance. Any suggestions on suitable tools to use?

[image: map]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one *brute force* solution:

1. Convert your raster from pixels to points
2. For all those points use network analyst to measure distance from point to Itaituba

Ensure you masked out the state Mato Grosso when you convert from pixel to points.

This will be computationally heavy so you may want to consider re-sampling your raster to a larger cell size to reduce number of points.

If your analysis is at the district level may be you could just use the district centroid that would significantly reduce combinations to test?

Comment: Seems like a possible solution. However I thought there would be a "not so brute force" solution by using tools like [Path Distance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/path-distance.htm).

So far I could not make any progress though because I don´t know how I can  take the road network into account.